# How to save result from loop and save them in a new array?

Tags: idl-programming-language

I am trying to save the results of loop in a new array, then plot them.
But now I can only save the last value comes from the loop. How can I save all the results from the loop?

```
for j=1,200 do begin
  h = where(o eq j,ct3)
  if (ct3 ne 0) then begin
    mag = a1[h].imag
    bcg = min(mag)
    deltay = pqq[plu2[j]]
    bcg1 = float(bcg)
    u = where(bcg1*deltay ne 0)
    bcg2 = bcg1[u]
    deltay1 = deltay[u]
    print,deltay1,bcg2
    plot,bcg2,deltay1,psym=5
  endif 
endfor
```

Answer (score 0):

To store a variable number of values each time through your loop, I would use a list and then the `toArray` method when you want the final array to plot.

For example, at the beginning of your code create a list to store the results in:

```
deltay_list = list()
```

Then in your loop, add elements to your list:

```
deltay_list->add, deltay1, /extract
```

The `EXTRACT` keyword indicates that you should add the individual elements of `deltay1`, not add `deltay` as a single element of the list. When you want to plot, then do:

```
deltay_array = deltay_list->toArray()
obj_destroy, deltay_list
plot, deltay_array
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it later!